# Web request goes through proxy which ip paddress wil noted clinet/proxy ip

Tags: proxy

I designing site. I made proxy in my web server.
When Client request for my website.Then I redirect the request to proxy and then target site.
Which ip address the request will send to target website ( the proxy / client ip address).
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source IP in the TCP connection will be, of course, the proxy's. If you want to know which IPs were used by the client and interim proxies, you should be able to find it in the header `X-Forwarded-For` (client IP) and `Via` headers (list of interim proxies).

Comment: Thanks Onon, how to forward the request as Client IP instead of proxy?

Comment: What do you mean? You want the source IP to remain that of the client?

Comment: Yes, Source IP is to be  a client. How can I do this?  I set up proxy to avoid cross domain functionality in the web browser. But Ultimately I Need to send the request as from the Client IP.

Comment: The proxy software cannot do that by itself, because it operates in layer 7 of the network stack. You're trying to modify headers from layer 2 and 3 (IP/TCP). What you **actually need** is called a *transparent intercepting proxy*. It's a set-up in which you set up your machine to act as a router or a bridge, force the packets into your proxy software, and then rewrite their headers to appear as if your machine was not an actual endpoint to the traffic. You can find internet tutorials on how to set-up such a system (look for `transparent proxy`).